# Forward Kerberos Authentication on Ansible

Tags: nginx, kerberos, ansible, winrm

I have an ansible control machine (host-A) that need to talk with host-C, an Windows machine that doesn't have local users (It's an Active Directory).

host-A doesn't have network access to host-C, but the communication it's possible using host-B.

host-B it's a linux machine.

host-A access host-B through ssh.

Following this [article](http://corwinbrown.com/wrangling-windows-winrm/) I've created a nginx server to route WinRM traffic on **host-B**

```
server {
    listen 5986 default ssl;
    server_name localhost;

    ssl_certificate  ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl/nginx.key;

    location /host-c {
        proxy_pass https://host-c-address:5986/wsman;
    }
}
```

My ansible inventory for host-C it's like:

```
[windows]
host-c ansible_host=host-b ansible_winrm_path=host-c
```

And `group_vars` for windows is:

```
ansible_user: myuser
ansible_pass: andmypass
ansible_port: 5986
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_realm: HOSTCDOMAIN.LOCAL
ansible_winrm_scheme: https
ansible_winrm_transport: kerberos
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```

## Things I have tested so far

### 1 Test without Kerberos

Changed this line:
`ansible_winrm_transport: ssl`

This is not possible because host-c can't have local users.

```
fatal: [host-c]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ssl: 401 Unauthorized."}
```

### 2 Create a NAT to route kerberos 88 port to host-C

With this I could authenticate my user using Kerberos client but not inside ansible

krb5.conf:

```
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 default_realm = HOSTCDOMAIN.LOCAL
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = false

[realms]
 HOSTCDOMAIN.LOCAL = {
  kdc = host-b
 }

[domain_realm]
 .hostcdomain.local = HOSTCDOMAIN.LOCAL
```

Using local kerberos

```
# kinit myuser@HOSTCDOMAIN.LOCAL
Password for myuser@HOSTCDOMAIN.LOCAL:

# klist

Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: myuser@HOSTCDOMAIN.LOCAL

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
03/12/2016 20:23:35  03/13/2016 06:23:35  krbtgt/HOSTCDOMAIN.LOCAL@HOSTCDOMAIN.LOCAL
    renew until 03/19/2016 20:23:31
```

Ansible test with `ansible_winrm_transport: kerberos`

```
e# ansible-playbook test_win.yml -vvv
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
1 plays in test_win.yml

PLAY [Ping windows] ************************************************************

TASK [ping] ********************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/test_win.yml:5
<host-b> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: myuser on PORT 5986 TO host-b
fatal: [host-c]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "kerberos: (('Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information', 851968), ('Server not found in Kerberos database', -1765328377))"}
```

Can someone help me to figure out how to overcome this? I think I'm missing something.

It's possible for host-a to use host-b to authenticate on host-c?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using **delegate_to**? to **host-B**? If so, what was the result?

> delegate_to: host-B